# How to Access knowledge articles via permission set

Tags: knowledge

I want to enable access of salesforce  knowledge articles to user having license "Salesforce" and profile "Standard user". I have created permission set for "Salesforce" license and given app permissions that are necessary to access  the knowledge articles tab, also did data category visibility setting(All)and object setting(visible for Knowledge object).But still I am unable to access knowledge tab and the the articles from the article management tab. Can anyone help to figure this out?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check if the **Knowledge User** checkbox was set to _true_ on the User record?

Comment: Yes, It is checked already.On R & D basis, I cloned standard user profile  and created same kind of permission set for user having this "Cloned std user" profile.So I am able to read the articles after logging in by that user. But I am not  getting why it is not working for permission set on "Standard user" profile of salesforce license.